# How do I to use Pivot in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to use pivot in SQL Server. I made the below attempt, but it is not working.

This my table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable
(
    Nom NVARCHAR(MAX),
    Source_ NVARCHAR(MAX),
    Date_ DATETIME
)
```

This is my data:

```
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES ('XXX', 'YYY', '12/12/2021')
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES ('ZZZ', 'TTT', '12/12/2021')
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES ('DDD', 'TTT', '12/12/2021')
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES ('AAA', 'FFF', '12/12/2021')
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES ('WWW', 'BBB', '12/12/2021')
```

And this is my attempt:

```
SELECT 
    Nom,Source_
FROM
    (SELECT Nom,Source_ 
     FROM TestTable) d
PIVOT
    (MAX(Nom)
        FOR Source_ IN (Nom, Source_ )
    ) piv;
```

I get the error

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
> Invalid column name 'Nom'

Comment: What does "not working with me" mean in detail?

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
Invalid column name 'Nom'.

Comment: What are your expected results here? `for Source_ in (Nom,Source_ )` doesn't make much sense as none of your rows have the value `'nom'` or `'Source_'` in the column `Source_`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: This is at best a guess based on what you have attempted.*

Firstly, the reason for the error you put in the comments:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
> Invalid column name 'Nom'.

If we take the SQL you have *actually* given us, you don't get that error... If we run it, we get the following errors:

> Msg 265, Level 16, State 1, Line 28
> The column name "Nom" specified in the PIVOT operator conflicts with the existing column name in the PIVOT argument.
> Msg 265, Level 16, State 1, Line 28
> The column name "Source_" specified in the PIVOT operator conflicts with the existing column name in the PIVOT argument

(Line numbers relative to the code I wrote).

This is because you define `Nom` in both the aggregate *and* the `FOR` and you put `Source_` in the `FOR` and the `FOR`'s `IN` clause. For a pivot, you need to put the column you want to aggregate in the aggregate (which I assume should still be `Nom`) and then in the `FOR` you list to provide the **values** ni the `IN` for the column in the `FOR`. For your sample data that would be a value of `YYY`. This gives you a statement like this:

```sql
SELECT Nom,
       Source_
FROM (SELECT Nom,
             Source_
      FROM TestTable) d
PIVOT (MAX(Nom)
       FOR Source_ IN (YYY, TTT, FFF, BBB)) piv;
```

This, however, will still error has the outer `SELECT` is referencing the object aliases as `piv`, as that doesn't have a column `Nom` or `Source_`. it has 4 columns, defined in the `IN`: `YYY`, `TTT`, `FFF`, and `BBB`.

So, presumably, the final statement should be:

```sql
SELECT YYY,
       TTT,
       FFF,
       BBB
FROM (SELECT Nom,
             Source_
      FROM TestTable) d
PIVOT (MAX(Nom)
       FOR Source_ IN (YYY, TTT, FFF, BBB)) piv;
```

Personally, however, I prefer to not use the `PIVOT` operator, it's quite restrictive and instead use conditional aggregation; which is also transferable to other RDBMS:

```sql
SELECT MAX(CASE Source_ WHEN 'YYY' THEN Nom END) AS YYY,
       MAX(CASE Source_ WHEN 'TTT' THEN Nom END) AS TTT,
       MAX(CASE Source_ WHEN 'FFF' THEN Nom END) AS FFF,
       MAX(CASE Source_ WHEN 'BBB' THEN Nom END) AS BBB
FROM dbo.TestTable;
```